# Is there any "Show Brush On Surface" option in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

I found [this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Jwilkins/GSoC2011/Google_Summer_of_Code_2011_Preliminary_Documentation) in the threads from GSoC 2010 or 2011, but can't find it now in blender. Is there an option somewhere or an addon that project brush circle on top of the surface of your model?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. Can you give a link?

Comment: On-Surface Brush here http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Jwilkins/GSoC2011/Google_Summer_of_Code_2011_Preliminary_Documentation

Comment: By default, no. By script, maybe. Looks like a tremendously useful addition, though!

Comment: Just found it in the Onion Branch of the GSoC 2011 here: http://graphicall.org/272

Comment: But it doesn't work on my win8.1-64... at all... so can't test it. Btw, i think on-surface brush is pretty much a default in many if not every other sculpting software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this isn't currently possible in blender, I believe that for one of many reasons it wasn't included into blender, that happens with GSoC projects quite often, sadly. (Maybe why blender didn't get any projects this year, 2015). As a result this isn't possible.